# How to debug spurious TCP requests coming from our own application?

Tags: .net, security, debugging, tcp, virus

We have a .NET application which, on a certain server, keeps making various TCP requests which are being blocked by our firewall.

The application has no reason to try to access the Internet, it only needs to communicate with our database server.

It seems to be trying to contact a certain address at deploy.akamaitechnologies.com, which apparently hosts a vast number of different files for various people/companies.

How can I debug which part of our code this request is coming from? TCPView indicates the request is coming directly from our .exe.

The code uses nHibernate libraries, my first guess was that a library was trying to update itself automatically but then presumably the request wouldn't be issuing direct from our .exe?

Could our .exe be infected with a virus on that particular server? Our anti-virus is up-to-date and scanning the .exe reveals nothing.

EDIT: OK I've finally got Wireshark on the server, not sure what to do with the output though. A couple of things I've noticed is that it sends a "name query nbstat" to an IP address owned by RIPE Network Coordination Centre, and also a message from "src port caicci" to the http port again on an IP address owned by RIPE Network Coordination Centre. It's hard to track all of the relevant requests because I don't know in advance which IP addresses it will use (it's different every time), and Wireshark seems to crash due to the volume of data if I leave it capturing for more than a minute or so. Apparently you can't filter by process?

Comment: What was the contents of the web-request?  Open the firewall, trace the traffic and see what it is requesting.

Comment: use Fiddler2 or Wireshark to determine the type and nature of the outgoing traffic first.

Comment: @wal If it is the local machine's firewall blocking outbound then he will have to open the local firewall first for Wireshark to be able to see it?

Comment: Thanks both - I'm not allowed to install any software so I won't be able to use Fiddler or Wireshark, but I've asked the network security team if they can give me any more info on packet contents from the firewall.

Comment: @tcarvin local firewall wasnt stipulated, kasey, is it your local firewall blocking it or some other router/firewall? You dont need to install fiddler2, you can just run it in place.

Comment: @wal Thanks - it's the organisation-wide filewall blocking it, not a local one. I've put in a request to get Fiddler on the server, I'll have to wait for that to be approved first as we have very stringent security. Someone else had already installed TCPView.

Comment: wireshark is better (lower level) and will catch all outgoing traffic (not just http calls) but has a steeper learning curve.

Comment: @wal finally got Wireshark authorised on the server, please see edit to original post

Comment: @tcarvin finally managed to see what it's requesting but not sure what to make of it!

Comment: @kasey i'm not much help here but use TCPView to determine the IP addresses its contacting then use wireshark with a CaptureFilter on that ip address. see http://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureFilters.. even if you determine the traffic is "nasty" you are still stuck; perhaps you could replace the exe's on the prod machines with ones you compiled on a 'safe' machine (backup your prod exes first of course)

Comment: @wal thanks, in fact that's exactly what I've been doing but I'm just not sure how to interpret the results. Perhaps the best thing is just to pass it back to our network/security guys. We've already established that redeploying our exes with clean versions changes nothing, so maybe a system DLL is infected or something? Thanks for your help anyway!

Comment: @kasey Are you 100% sure the same process sending the requests is in the same location as your exe? sometimes a virus may take on the name of an existing exe, you can find this info from tcpview by right clicking and choosing process properties. You could try running `sfc /scannow` (as admin) to check the integrity of your windows installation. One more thing to try as an experiment is to compile a simple Console Application that does nothing and run it on this server to see if it starts sending stuff.

Comment: Don't worry about the source port on traffic coming from you server, it will be a random ephimeral port.  For traffic going out port 80 (HTTP), what does the request contain?  I'd hope to see enough information so you can figure out which of your subcomponents(dlls) is trying to communicate.  It's probably something as simple as self-updating or license validation, but you never know.

Comment: @wal thanks for the tip, I've checked and it's definitely our exe (same location)

Comment: @tcarvin it just keeps trying to send SYN, I guess because our firewall is blocking it so it can't even connect? There doesn't seem to be much in there to look at, unfortunately I can't paste the output here for security reasons.

Comment: If the firewall is preventing the connect then you will not see the request.  Perhaps set the local hosts file to temporarily map deploy.akamaitechnologies.com to a local IP address so the connection will be allowed (even if the request will fail) just so you can see what is getting requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure the exe that is running called `YourApp.exe` is actually the one you think it is? Can you do an md5sum of a trusted exe and compare with one on the server?

> How can I debug which part of our code this request is coming from? TCPView indicates the request is coming directly from our .exe.

Assuming you dont have Visual Studio installed on the server (or can't remote debug) then you can get a dump of the process and analyze on your own machine. Is it a .NET4 process?

Comment: What I'm thinking of trying next is backing up the exes on the server, then redeploying fresh copies on top of them to see if the spurious requests still occur. I don't have the exact original exes. I don't know anything about analyzing a dump but presumably this would point you at the method that was running at the time you took the snapshot? I'm not sure if that would help because these exes process vast amounts of information, so by the time I've seen the web request and pressed a button to take a snapshot, it will probably be in a totally different part of the program...we're on .NET 3.5.

Comment: yes, you can take a dump file easily using task manager. If it was running as a .net4 process you could analyze the dumpfile in Visual Studio 2010 and get a visual idea of what all the threads are doing (google Parallel Stacks) but since you're .net3.5 you can't do this. you really need to get a packet sniffer on there; you are running tcpview on it so why not fiddler2?

Comment: @kasey what was causing the issue?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know, we still suspect malware but it's out of my hands now. Will update if the network security team find a resolution but I suspect they will just rebuild the server to be safe, since it's not exhibiting this behaviour on other servers. Figured I'd close the question off to avoid wasting anyone's time looking at it further. Thanks for your help!